# What is the difference between git reset --hard HEAD and git clean --force -d?

Tags: git

Is there a difference? And if so what is the difference between `git reset --hard HEAD` and `git clean --force -d`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git clean` removes *untracked* files. `git reset` only affects *tracked* files.